# Find a set that is closed but the reverse image is not closed.

Tags: real-analysis

I have a function such that it is x^2 for x when x is not equal to 1 and 3 otherwise. I want to find a set for the range such that it is closed but it’s reverse image is not closed. This is to show that it is not continuous. Now, I found such a set that is open but not open in the reverse image however if anyone can give me a hint or tell me a closed set that fails to be closed in the reverse image, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Take that open set $A$ that you found and then $\mathbb R\setminus A$ will be a closed set with the property that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Well you stated that you had already found an open set that is not open in the reverse image, so I will work from that fact. Let $U$ be that open set you referred to. Then $U^c$ is a closed set. Also, $f^{-1}(U^c)=(f^{-1}(U))^c$. We already know that $f^{-1}(U)$ is not open, so $(f^{-1}(U))^c$ is not closed. That should give you what you are looking for.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).